# Javascript object is passing to the controller as null object "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am working on openstreetmap with asp.net core 3.0. I am trying to get the latitude, longitude other details from the map as javascript object and sendng it to the controller. For that, I have implemented a AJAX request to pass the javascript object to the controller. But the controller receives the value of the object as null. I am wondering where am I doing the mistake. Or is it a version problem? Here is my code below,

My Model Class

```
public class LocationModel
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller-Action method

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(LocationModel details)
    {
        return Json(new { result = "OK"});
    }
```

My client-side code

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
        var name = window.prompt("Add Location Name:", "Text");
        var note = window.prompt("Add Note:", "Text");
        var latitude = e.latlng.lat;
        var longitude = e.latlng.lng;

        var locationdetails = { "LocationName": name, "Note": note, "Latitude": latitude, "Longitude": longitude };
        console.log(locationdetails);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/Save',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({details: locationdetails}),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Error has occurred..");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here, **locationdetails** variable contains all the details which I need to pass to the controller. From the AJAX call, it is not working. If someone can show my mistake, that would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this `public JsonResult Save([FromBody]LocationModel details)`

Comment: Already tried. But not working. I think it is a version problem. I am working in .net core 3.0 version. I tried also in .net framework 4.7.2 and my code is working

Comment: Try to modify `data` option of jQuery ajax using `data: JSON.stringify(locationdetails)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the controller receives the value of the object as null.

To get the expected data, you can modify the code like below.

*jQuery AJAX code*

```
$.ajax({

    //...
    //other options
    //...

    data: JSON.stringify(locationdetails),
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.result);
    },

    //...
});
```

*Controller action*

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save([FromBody]LocationModel details)
{
    return Json(new { result = "OK" });
}
```

*Test result*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well C# model is with upper case for the keys. The javascript object

```
var locationdetails = { "name": name, "note": note, "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude };
```

has the keys in lowercase. The C# middleware mapper cannot map and it is resolved to null. Try the following

```
var locationdetails = { "Name": name, "Note": note, "Latitude": latitude, "Longitude": longitude };
```

You might be missing locationId as I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I want to store the data to database. so LocationId will be in auto-increment mode.

Comment: @Mahbub did the answer help you?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have changed the javascript object property like my model class. Moreover, for the manual testing, I have also added the LocationId value in the javascript object.  But my controller parameter is showing null when debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `alert` on `data` when your argument is `response` in your success function – below is broken:

```js
            success: function (response) {
                alert(data);
            }
```

**(EDIT FOR CLARITY)**

Below should be working:

```js
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
```

Comment: Not making any difference. It is showing the same result.

Comment: ?? Are you sure you understood what I was saying? You are trying to `alert` on variable `data` but you do not have that variable defined anywhere. do `alert(response)` and it will work @Mahbub

Comment: Yes, I have tried your suggestion already. In the alert box, it shows [object Object] for your code. I defined data as data: JSON.stringify({details: locationdetails})

Comment: @Mahbub That is because that is how `alert` handles all objects. You could put a `console.log` there and see your full response and that your problem is fixed. And the data you defined as `JSON.stringify...` is not the same data that is referenced in your success function.

Comment: Yes, from console.log I can see the response. It is showing my controller-action return result. But I want to get my data in the controller where the controller parameter is showing null. @Pytth